# Is it possible to login in to another website with a php button?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, authentication, laravel-jetstream

I am trying to make this function in laravel jetstream projecet that I need to login to another website (ex. Facebook, Twitter) using the credentials (ex. email, password) of my logged-in or authenticated user. I am thinking on specifying the url in the , but I am not sure on how to get the data from my database and populate the form of another website and automatically loggedin my user.

The problem that I have is that I have to connect two websites that we made using the credentials (email, password) of one website and used those credentials to open another website, so when the user logged-in to website 1, the dashboard will open and will have a link for website 2 and if the user visited website 2, the user will automatically be logged in to website 2 using the credentials of website 1.

Is this possible using php or I need to use a library for this one? I have no idea on how to do this, is this possible? Thank you.

Comment: Try writing a simple page to do auto form submission to the target domain (but it is possible that the target domain will check that the source is another domain and reject it).  Read **Same-origin policy** and **Cross-Site Request Forgery Prevention** ,etc. for further details

Comment: The purpose here is unclear. Sites like facebook or twitter offer OAuth2 as a means to allow your site to act on behalf of a user if the user gives their consent.

Comment: The problem that I have is that I have to connect two websites that we made using the credentials (email, password) of one website and used those credentials to open another website,  so when the user logged-in to website 1, the dashboard will open and will have a link for website 2 and if the user visited website 2, the user will automatically be logged in to website 2 using the credentials of website 1.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot control the user's browser through your own website and log them into another site. That would be a major security risk.

Answer (score -1):

You can use firebase that is easy to set up and has all the login methods above you asked for.

https://console.firebase.google.com/project/